# Specifying non-editable string in settings.bundle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have noticed that some applications add entries into the settings.bundle that simply represent a fixed/non-editable string.

[image]

I only see these in the list, and the only one close is "Text Field" but thats editable.

[image]

Is there a way to specify this in the Root.plist ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of selecting TextField use Title

Comment: I'm trying this, but when I change it title it is no longer displayed at all. Any input?

Comment: @HCHogan probably best adding a new question with some detail

Answer (score 11):

Indeed you have to use title instead of textField and more specifically in order to produce the example you mention use the following tips:

- In settings bundle under Root.plist add a new type title
- Set title value to "Version"
- In the same item add a new row and set this to 'Default value'
- Set Default Value to "1.1.1"

This will produce a non-editable text field with title value on the left and Default value on the right.